# Getting sbt task dependencies to work

Tags: dependencies, task, sbt

I am trying to define a dependency between a custom task and an existing task (in this case compile in Compile), following: [Task Dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks#dependencies) in sbt documentation.  However, closest I could get is this:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

val hello = TaskKey[Unit]("hello", "Prints 'Hello World'")

val helloTaskA = hello := {
  println("Hello World")
}

val helloTaskB = hello <<= hello.dependsOn(compile in Compile)

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  helloTaskA, 
  helloTaskB      
)
```

This seems to work. hello triggers a compile, if necessary, before executing.  However, the thing I don't get is why I need to include both helloTaskA and helloTaskB in my settings.  If I don't include helloTaskA in the settings, I get:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting: 
[error] 
[error]   *:hello from *:hello
```

I understand that because helloTaskA is immutable, helloTaskB is a different task, but I would think it would silently include helloTaskA.  Moreover, I'm not sure what it means to include two settings for tasks with the same task key like this.